# can we use con HCl zn amalgam to reduce alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

all says that we can't use zn con HCl to reduce alcohol. can anyone explain this with the mechanism or with explanations

Comment: I think we can because when reducing aldehyde or ketone, In mechanism alcohol is formed which further reduces to give hydrocarbons.

Comment: but some peoples say that alcohol is not formed as an intermediate in this reaction

Comment: I have answered with mechanism. Take a look at that

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mechanism for reduction of aldehyde/ketone by clemmenson reduction.

[image]

Note that alcohol is formed as intermediate which further reduces. Considering that alcohol can be reduced by Zn/HCl